# Maximum concurrent kernels for devices of compute capability 3.0

Tags: cuda, gpu

What is the maximum number of concurrent kernels possible for NVIDIA devices of compute capability 3.0 ? I hope its not the same as the one for Compute Capability 2.0..

Comment: If you're satisfied with an answer to a question you pose you can and should 'accept' it by clicking on the 'tick' mark at the left hand side of the answer, see http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask for more info.

Comment: @PaulCaheny I couldn't even get a chance to check back soon. I just now saw your response. I had read the CUDA C programming guide where its mentioned, devices with compute capability 2.0 support 16 concurrent kernels. So I just thought may be its higher for devices with CC 3.0. Anyway Thanks for the answer. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the CUDA C programming guide version 4.2:

3.2.5.3 Concurrent Kernel Execution
The maximum number of kernel launches that a device can execute concurrently is sixteen.